# The problem of adding the code to the program

Tags: asp.net-core, ckeditor, bundler

I want to addg ckeditor 4.11.4 in my ASP.NET Core MVC project with bundle.
I use ASP.NET Core 2.2 and the bootstrap bundling is working.

This is my package.json :

```js
{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "name": "asp.net",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": { },
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "4.3.1",
    "font-awesome": "4.7.0",
    "jquery": "3.4.1",
    "popper.js": "2.0.0-next.4",
    "ckeditor": "4.11.4"
  }
}
```

And this is my bundleconfig.json file:

```js
[
  {
    "outputFileName": "wwwroot/vendor.min.css",
    "inputFiles": [
      "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
      "node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css",
      "node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css",
      "node_modules/ckeditor/contents.css"

    ],
    "minify": { "enabled": false }
  },
  {
    "outputFileName": "wwwroot/vendor.min.js",
    "inputFiles": [
      "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
      "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
      "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
      "node_modules/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"

    ],
    "minify": { "enabled": false }
  }
]
```

But this does not work. What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Font-awesome css references use sprites and webfonts folders !
Copy font-awesome folder to wwwroot/lib folder.

and use in head

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/font-awesome/css/fontawesome.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/font-awesome/css/regular.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/font-awesome/css/solid.min.css" />
```